# C++ If statement error: expected ';' before '{' token

Tags: c++, if-statement

I was writing this out for fun:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int Arsenal = rand()%3;
int Norwich = rand()%3;

int main () {
  if (Arsenal > Norwich) {
    cout << "Arsenal win the three points, they are in the Top Four";
    return 0;
  } else if (Arsenal == Norwich) {
    cout << "The game was a draw, both teams gained a point";
    return 0;
  } else (Norwich > Arsenal) {
      cout << "Norwich won, Arsenal lost";
      return 0;
    }
}
```

and I tried to compile it in g++, yet I get this error:

```
arsenalNorwich.cpp: In function, 'int main'
arsenalNorwich.cpp:15:30: error: expected ';' before '{' token
```

I have no idea what I did wrong, and neither does the CS tutor at my school. Although it's just for fun, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: The tutor doesn't? ............

Comment: *"I have no idea what I did wrong"* - you picked a school with a tutor who doesn't know C++, by the sound of it! +1 for posting a well-formed question, despite being brand new to stackoverflow.

Comment: In the future, tell us which line is line 15. Saves everybody from having to count lines.

Comment: decent question, but flagged as not being useful for anyone else ever.

Answer (score 8):

you missed one `if` here:

```
  else if (Norwich > Arsenal)
  ///^^^if missing
```

Meanwhile, it is not good to put

```
 int Arsenal = rand()%3;
 int Norwich = rand()%3;
```

before `main`. Another point is that you should first set random seed before calling `rand()`.

Your `if-else` can be simplified as follows:

```
if (Arsenal > Norwich) {
   cout << "Arsenal win the three points, they are in the Top Four";
} else if (Arsenal == Norwich) {
   cout << "The game was a draw, both teams gained a point";
} else { //^^^no need to compare values again since it must be Norwich > Arsenal
         //when execution reaches this point
   cout << "Norwich won, Arsenal lost";
}
return 0;
```

Comment: +1 correct, but if it isn't < and isn't ==, one could say that there is a missing `if` or an *extra* expression ;)

Comment: @msw I would go a step further, and say that `else` should be *preferred* over `else if (expression)` - it's more readable in the sense that the reader can easily figure out what happens in *every possible case*, because you've provided a final catch-all.

Comment: Can't you simply leave the `return 0` part to outside the if statements?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Of course. But now the reader has to look outside the conditional blocks to determine some of it's behaviour (which may not be as trivial as `return 0`). IMO this is less clear. If the `else` behaviour is to do nothing, I usually like to document that with a `else {} // do nothing`, so that my block of conditionals is fully self-documenting for every possible scenario. I acknowledge that this is just a style preference however.